# Mapped culverts information

Tags: usa

I was wondering where I can find maps of culverts that runs under interstates?

I'm in Indiana. I wrote an email to [INDOT](http://www.in.gov/indot/) (Indiana Department of Transportation) and they said they don't have such information.

I searched Indiana Map Atlas and somehow wasn't sure if culverts were related to hydrology maps?

Like, canal, ditches, connectors, drainage?

They don't have a map specifically associated with "culverts".

Does anyone have an idea about it?

Answer (score 4):

the System 1 Bridges (INDOT) data set from IndianaMAP combined with one of the hydrology data sets from the same source may give you what you are looking for:

Bridges:
http://maps.indiana.edu/layerGallery.html?category=Bridges

Streamlines:
http://maps.indiana.edu/layerGallery.html?category=WaterBodies

If you have ArcGIS, I'd suggest using the Streams, Ditches, etc. (NHD, 2008) data and doing a select by location with the target layer as the bridges feature class and the Source layer as the hydrography using a spatial selection method of within a distance of the source layer feature.

Comment: Thanks. I already had these two maps. I'm also checking flowlines (classified and unclassified). I just wasn't sure which category culverts fall into. It should be part of infrastructures, right? But since I'm considering all passage ways (natural and artificial) through interstates, these maps should provide enough information.

Comment: No problem. Yea if you are considering all passage ways of water through interstates (regardless of size) then the streams & ditches and flowlines data sets could be used with ArcMap's intersect tool to generate point features where they meet highways. You could do some field work to ground proof the resultant point feature class.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got directed to the Bridge Inspection Section of INDOT. They do not have maps for culverts. But they do provide a database including inventories of all bridges and culverts. The database manager was very helpful in that she created a read-only account with which I can have access to the database.

Comment: That is not a generally available account, I assume? Or are you allowed to publish it? In that case, please put the account data into the answer.

Comment: @Jan Doggen The account was created specifically for me alone. I don't think it's publishable. But the answer provided is letting people with the same needs know who to contact.